# Netty multithreading broken in version 4.1 ? Unable to process short queries after long ones?

Tags: multithreading, netty

I just want to setup a very common server : it must accept connections and make some business calculations to return the answer. Calculations can be short or long -> I need some kind of ThreadPoolExecutor to execute these calculations.

In netty 3, that we were using since a long time, this was achieved very easily, by just using an ExecutionHandler in the pipeline, before my BusinessHandler.

But now trying to setup the same thing in netty 4, i read in the documentation that ExecutionHandler was not existing anymore, and that i add to specify a EventExecutor when adding my BusinessHandler to the channel pipeline.

```
DefaultEventExecutorGroup applicativeExecutorGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(10);
...
ch.pipeline().addLast(applicativeExecutorGroup, businessHandler);
```

It works for very basic scenarios (only short queries), but not in the following one. **The reason is that DefaultEventExecutorGroup will not select a free worker, but any one based on a round-robin.**

- A first request (R1) comes, is assigned T1 (Thread 1 of the DefaultEventExecutorGroup), and will take a long time (say 1 minute).
- Then a few other queries Ri (i=2 to 10) are received. They are assigned Ti, and are also processed successfully.
- But when R11 comes, it is assigned again T1, due to the round-robin algorithm implemented in DefaultEventExecutorGroup, and the query is queued after the long R1. As a result, it will not start its processing before one minute, and that is clearly an unacceptable delay. In concrete scenarios, clients never get the answer, because they time out waiting for the answer before we start the processing.
- And this continue like this. One query every 10 queries will just fail, because queued after the long one in the only busy thread, while all the other threads of the Group were just idle.

Is there another configuration of my pipeline that would work ? For example, does a implemntation of EventExecutor exist that would just work like a standard Executor (select a FREE worker).
Or is it just a bug in netty 4.1 ? It would looks very strange, as this looks as a very common scenario for any server.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you explained above I think you want to use `UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor` as a replacement for `DefaultEventExecutorGroup`. Or if ordering is important `NonStickyEventExecutorGroup`.